# Setting up CIFilter in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-image

How does one translate the last line of the following ObjC code to Swift:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CIFilter *clampFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineClamp"];

[clampFilter setValue:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&transform objCType:@encode(CGAffineTransform)] forKey:@"inputTransform"];
```

The following line

```
clampFilter.setValue(transform, forKey: "inputTransform")
```

produces

```
Type 'CGAffineTransform' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`NSValue` has a constructor that takes a `CGAffineTransform` argument:

```
let transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
let clampFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineClamp")

let val = NSValue(CGAffineTransform: transform)
clampFilter.setValue(val, forKey: "inputTransform")
```

Update for **Swift 3:**

```
let transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
let clampFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineClamp")!
let val = NSValue(cgAffineTransform: transform)
clampFilter.setValue(val, forKey: "inputTransform")
```

Comment: It's crashing in Swift 3.1. Can you post any example of  CIAffineClamp or CIAffineTile.

Comment: @ChanWarde: Please check if the update works for you.

Comment: hello @Martin R, it's not working even only "CIKaleidoscope" in TileEffect is working for me. All other filters are returning nil image. I don't find any example, question or reference for it. Can you please add some code. Or I should add a new question for it??

Comment: @ChanWarde: I would suggest to ask a new question. Don't forget to add the code that you tried and a clear description where it fails.

Answer (score 2):

This might do.

```
var transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
var clampFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineClamp")
var value = NSValue(CGAffineTransform: transform)
clampFilter.setValue(value, forKey: "inputTransform")
```

Comment: You should always use `let` in swift unless you are specifically going to change the value in the future.